# Know which column has the result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a big database (13K registers, with 100 columns).I use a live search script, to extract results.

It's a networking database, with IP ranges, DSL numbers, some Circuit_ID etc.

Also, Indeed the whole result, I want to know which column has the result the user is typing.

Which command in PHP could let me get the name of that column?

Comment: Are you using a prewritten live search library, maybe it can return this information. if it's a script you've written, you need to put this in the SQL, there's nothing built into PHP or SQL to do it.

Comment: I think you need to re-prase the question in a way we can understand what you are doing and what you actually want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all rows, compare each row and get the col index no. of the match. USe Brute FOrce !!